# Find double integration given a table of data?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm able to gather data from a device: The time passed and acceleration.
Given this sample data, I'm trying to find displacement.

I'm attempting to do this by double integration via Riemann sum, using the Trapezoidal method.
I know how to integrate once:
x = time data, y = acceleration data
T = (x2 − x1)(y1 + 2y2 + 2y3 + · · · + 2yn−1 + yn)/2

This will give me velocity. I'm not sure what to do from here in order to get displacement, since I'm given a table of data and not functions.
Am I just supposed to apply the process where the new data is the y1, 2y2, 2y3, etc?

Please help!

The code below uses basic sample data, but when actually implemented will be using collected acceleration data.
My code for implementation is below:

```
    int main()
{

  const int SIZE = 6;
  int dataV[SIZE] = {2,4,6,8,10,12};
  int timeV[SIZE] ={100,300,500,700,900,1100};

  //L = (x2 - x1)(y1 + y2 + ... + yn-1)                                         
  //R = (x2 - x1)(y2 + y3 + ... + yn)                                           
  //P = (x2 - x1)(y1 + 4y2 + 2y3 + 4y4 + ... + 2yn-2 + 4yn-1 + yn) / 3          



  //Get x2 - x1                                                                 
  int timePart = timeV[1] - timeV[0];
  //FIND INTEGRAL USING TRAPEZOIDAL METHOD                                      
  //get summation of data values                                                
    int sum = dataV[0]; //sum begins with first element in data array           
    //T = (x2 − x1)(y1 + 2y2 + 2y3 + · · · + 2yn−1 + yn)/2                      
    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE - 1; i++)
    {
      sum += 2 * dataV[i];
    }
    sum += dataV[SIZE - 1];

    cout << "Sum = " << sum << endl;
    float integral1 = timePart * sum;
     integral1 /= 2;
    cout << "Integral1 = " << integral1 << endl;
  //multiple time and data values                                               





  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't just compute the final velocity, fill an array with all intermediate velocities and integrate it. (You can also work this out without intermediate storage).

Comment: what do you mean by intermediate velocities?